# Delete row in DGV if int is incremented?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a method to save each row in a datagridview into the database, but I want to remove each row if it gets saved. I have this method:

```
public static void SaveMajEq(MajorEquipment_CreateView CView)
{
    rowCount = 0;
    // For each cell in the DataGrid, stores the information in a string.
    for (rows = 0; rows < CView.dgvCreate.Rows.Count; rows++)
    {
        if (CView.dgvCreate.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value != null)
        {
            // Creates a model, then populates each field from the cells in the table.
            MeModel = new MajorEquipment_Model();
            MeModel.EquipmentNumber = Convert.ToString(CView.dgvCreate.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value);
            MeModel.EquipmentType = Convert.ToString(CView.dgvCreate.Rows[rows].Cells[1].Value);
            MeModel.Location = Convert.ToString(CView.dgvCreate.Rows[rows].Cells[2].Value);
            MeModel.Notes = Convert.ToString(CView.dgvCreate.Rows[rows].Cells[3].Value);

            Database_Facade.Operation_Switch(OPWRITE);
        }
        CView.dgvCreate.Rows.RemoveAt(rows);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(rowCount + " Entries stored in database.");
}
```

`rowCount` gets incremented in a `try/catch` method in a separate class, so if anything occurs, it wont be incremented. What I want to do is only implement this line:

```
CView.dgvCreate.Rows.RemoveAt(rows);
```

**only if `rowCount` is incremented each time.** I'm not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert the loop order

```
for (rows = CView.dgvCreate.Rows.Count - 1; rows >= 0 ; rows--)
```

Looping backward allow to remove the row processed by the loop without affecting the index of the next row to process.

Comment: so would I use this to replace my current `for` line?

Comment: Yes, your actual for loop skips a row when you delete one because when you delete the row at X position the row at position X+1 shifts to position X, then you increment the indexer and skips the row that was at position X+1. Still unclear what is the role of the counter variable. (I have used the name X for the indexer instead of your `rows` to avoid confusion)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise the significance of that. The counter variable is used to show how many rows were stored in the database. I figured that *might* be a good variable to use to indicate whether a row was saved or not? I could be wrong though

Comment: Well, supposing that the operation that saves the rows to the database is `Database_Facade.Operation_Switch(OPWRITE);` then perhaps you could return a boolean true to signal the correct save or false for error. You could incremente a local variable and remove the global `counter`. (It is considered a bad practice to have globals when you could easily avoid them).